# how to drop a user in oracle,Unable to drop a user

Tags: oracle

Initially I am connected to user u1.

```
connect u1/p1;

select user from dual;

USER:
----
U1
```

Now I have connected to sys.

```
connect sys/knl_test7 as sysdba;

select user from dual;

USER:
----
SYS
```

Now I have done

```
drop user u1 cascade;
drop user u1 cascade
 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
```

Comment: There is apparently another connection that uses that user. `select machine, program, logon_time from v$session where username = 'U1'`

Comment: You could kill all those sessions with that user and then srop it.